Question about Formatting Labels in ggplot2 with geom_text_repel
I am writing to ask a specific question regarding the possibility of formatting a part of the text in bold within a label created with geom_text_repel (ggrepel) in ggplot2.
In my case, I have the following string:
right_label <- paste0(Dati$Lotto, sep=", ", round(Dati$VixME), sep=" ", "mPa s, ", sprintf("%.1f", Dati$increase), "%")

I would like to display the percentage value in bold, while keeping the other parts of the label in normal font. The value I would like to format in bold is:
sprintf("%.1f", Dati$increase), "

Is it possible to achieve this?
Below the whole code and the picture of the graph, with circled the parts I would like to be made bold.
# Creazione del dataframe in R
Dati <- data.frame(
  Prodotto = c("PU 115k", "PU 115 std", "PU 115k", "PU 115FI", "PU 115FI", "PU 115FI"),
  VixME = c(28350, 28800, 31250, 25500, 36900, 28850),
  Ref = c("PU 204", "PU 204", "PU 204", "PU 204", "PU 204", "PU 204"),
  Lotto = c("lt. 103694", "lt. 76823", "lt. 77763", "lt. 106156", "lt. 103703", "lt. 76093"),
  VixLab = c(25700, 27950, 29050, 25300, 35500, 27250),
  class = c("green", "blue", "green", "red", "red", "red"),
  increase = c(10.3, 3.0, 7.6, 0.8, 3.9, 5.9)
)



library(scales)
library(ggrepel)
theme_set(theme_classic())



# Modifica delle etichette con 'increase' formattato a una cifra decimale
left_label <- paste0(Dati$Lotto, sep=", ", round(Dati$VixLab), sep=" " , "mPa s")
right_label <- paste0(Dati$Lotto, sep=", ", round(Dati$VixME), sep=" ", "mPa s, ", sprintf("%.1f", Dati$increase), "%")


p <- ggplot(Dati) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend=2, y=VixLab, yend=VixME, col=class), size=.75, show.legend=TRUE) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=1, linetype="dashed", size=.1) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=2, linetype="dashed", size=.1) +
  scale_color_manual(
    labels = c("a", "b", "c"), 
    values = c("green" = "#0D1BBe", "red" = "#BE0D1B", "blue" = "#438C2A")
  ) +
  labs(x="", y="viscosity (mPa s)") +  
  xlim(.5, 2.5) + ylim(min(Dati$VixLab, Dati$VixME), (1.1 * max(Dati$VixLab, Dati$VixME)))

p <- p + 
  geom_text_repel(label=left_label, y=Dati$VixLab, x=rep(1, NROW(Dati)), hjust=1.1, size=2.5) +
  geom_text_repel(label=right_label, y=Dati$VixME, x=rep(2, NROW(Dati)), hjust=-0.1, size=2.5) +
  geom_text(label="Viscosity CQ", x=1, y=1.1*(max(Dati$VixLab, Dati$VixME)), hjust=1.2, size=3.5) +
  geom_text(label="Viscosity after test", x=2, y=1.1*(max(Dati$VixLab, Dati$VixME)), hjust=-0.1, size=3.5) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 2, 1, 2), "cm"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom", 
    legend.box.spacing = unit(-0.5, 'cm')
  )

p



Does this answer your question: Making only part of a label bold while using geom_label_repel() in ggplot

Try with something like right_label <- paste0(   gsub(" ", "~", Dati$Lotto),   "~", round(Dati$VixME), "~mPa~s",   sprintf("~bold('%.1f')", Dati$increase), "*'%'" ). And add parse=TRUE to the geom_text_repel whichs add the right label

Thank you Stefano, it works. I am going to study deeply this string to understand but it works fine.
